# jest snapshot error when testing on CircleCI

Tags: continuous-integration

I had a problem with jest snapshots not matching when running on circleCI, when they were passing locally.

The fix is quite simple and I'll post it below in the answers section.

Answer (score -3):

make sure that the node version on circleCI and locally are the same.

check your local node version then specify in **circle.yml** in your project root, like so:

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 8.1.4
```

Comment: why is this downvoted? It's the answer to a problem that I experienced.